# Python does not recognize a "New Line" command

Tags: python, return, newline, enter

I am a newbie when it comes to programming but I do have a little experience. My problem is this. I installed Python on my laptop on which the "Return" key is "Shift+Enter." For Python, the Return key gives the command to start a new line while enter gives the command to run the line of code. Python does not recognize "Shift+Enter" as "Return"

Simple Example:

```
>>>def f(n)
```

When I hit enter, it doesn't start a new line but tries to run "def f(n)" which yields an error. Same thing if I use Shift+Enter (which is "Return"). Help?

Comment: -1. Python makes no distinction between "enter" and "return".

Answer (score 4):

This should be

```
def f(n):
```

Note the `:`.

Comment: You forgot this: http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions

Answer (score 1):

A function declaration ends in a colon (:). Type

```
def f(n):
```

and Python will allow you to enter more lines.